# What does those padlock and plus symbols mean in my solution explorer?

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2012, ide

[image]

I think it is something related to Team Foundation Service, but what does that mean ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The lock means that the item is checked in, and the + means that an add operation is pending for the item.

You can see the full list of [TFS Icons on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245455.aspx).

Comment: My item with a + isn't being recognized by the project when I try to access functions inside of it. I am guessing because it's not been 'added' to the project. So how do I add it? I initially thought I added it because I right clicked on the project and selected 'add new file'.

Answer (score 9):

A plus means the item has not yet been added to source control.

A padlock means the item is in source control but has not been checked out for editing

A check mark (which you don't show) means the item is in source control but has been checked out for editing.

Answer (score 2):

`+` means it is newly added but not checked in
`lock` means it is present on tfs and is checked in.(read able mode only). when you start to type anything in the file it will be checked out(a tick mark will show on the file)